# CSS Style property names -- going from the regular version to the JS property camelCase version and vice versa

Tags: javascript, css

Does there exist a provision for obtaining the corresponding names?

A function I'm writing has to both set the style via `element.style[propnameCamelCase]` and retrieve the existing rendered value via `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element,'').getPropertyValue(propname-regular)`, and I can hardly justify having to pass two separate but semantically identical arguments to this function.

I know that for most of them it's a fairly straightforward transcription between camelCase and hyphen-delimited with the same words, so I can use regexes to convert them. But maybe there are a few that are not like this?

Off the top of my head I'm having a hard time figuring out how to deal with the capitalized letters for camel case with regular expressions.

**edit**: Ah, I could use a function for regex replace, each time I see a hyphen, convert next letter to upper case.

Comment: css properties generally have hyphens, not underscores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you're basically reinventing [jQuery.css()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js). Maybe a look at how jQuery solved the camelCase problem might help: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L600

Comment: I guess if their solution is to actually convert to camelcase then that is what I'll do: `function toCamelCase(variable) { return variable.replace(/-([a-z])/g,function(str,letter){ return letter.toUpperCase();});}`

Comment: I don't know your circumstances/environment/demands, but it's usually not a bad idea to use (such wide-spread and heavily used) libraries like jQuery. They usually consider things you don't even know about (like IE not camelcasing the -ms vendor prefix properly). I'm not evangelizing jQuery, but you should have waterproof reasons not to use it (or dojo, or whatever library floats your boat).

Comment: Conversely, jQuery is a huge and often slow library that you may not want to add for a single function

Comment: I've encountered sites where up to four instances of different versions of jQuery got loaded into various iframes made by different developers who probably agreed that "it's not usually a bad idea to use a widespread and heavily used library". 
Apart from the sheer bloat, it creates unknowns which make debugging harder. This alone strikes me as a waterproof reason to seek to *avoid using jQuery in general*. For prototyping, it's a fine tool, but when making components for the wider web ecosystem, it's a liability.

Comment: @rodneyrehm Waterproof reason not to use jQuery is that after you use it you still don't even know about the things you need to consider.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to ask question about the same thing (and I intended to name it "Translate css names to\from javascript counterparts"). Somehow I ended up writing my own solution.

```
function cssNameToJsName(name)
{
    var split = name.split("-");
    var output = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && split[i].length > 0 && !(i == 1 && split[i] == "ms"))
        {
            split[i] = split[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + split[i].substr(1);
        }
        output += split[i];
    }
    return output;
}

function jsNameToCssName(name)
{
    return name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to mention that `CSSStyleDeclaration.style.setProperty` accepts css/hyphen type property names without conversion, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)

Try this hyphenated property, for example:

```
document.body.style.setProperty("background-color", "red");
```

You can also do this:

```
document.body.style["background-color"] = "silver";
```

These approaches - if you can use them - may be simpler.